# gdb eflags register on x86_64

Tags: gdb, eflags

Has the eflags register in gdb on amd64 platform the same meaning as rflags with a wider register? Gdb only shows me the eflags register on my machine with amd64.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register):

```
RFLAGS
bits 32-63      Reserved
```

So yes: there is no additional info in the higher bits.